# Find the set of all equivalence classes of the relation $\phi \sim \psi \iff \models(\phi \iff \psi)$

Tags: logic, order-theory, equivalence-relations

Find the set of all equivalence classes of the relation $\phi \sim \psi \iff \models(\phi \iff \psi)$ All sentences consist of only one variable.

Since these sentences have to be equivalent and each of them consists of only one variable, then there are $2 \cdot 2$ ways to assign the logical values of the sentences to the values of the variables. And so I can think of four equivalence classes. Let $\pi(x)$ be the logical value of a sentence whose variable has the value of $x$. Then to describe my equivalence classes I'd like to use this ordered pair: $(\pi(0), \pi(1))$. And so, the equivalence classes: 
$$\{[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1] \}$$
Is this solution correct?

Comment: Yes, and you should probably mention the Completeness Theorem for proof that $\vdash (\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi)$ if and only if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ agree under any assignment of the single variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Put a different (maybe a little more intuitive) way: every sentence built up form a single variable $P$ (and any number of logical operators) will be logically equivalent to one of four sentences: $P$, $\neg P$, $\top$, or $\bot$

Comment: I stated in the problem that all sentences consist of only one variable

Comment: @Aemilius Right. $P$ is a sentence that consists of a single variable, no? And same is true for $Q$. At least, that's how I interpreted your question: $\phi$ and $\psi$ are sentences consisting of one variable. ... though what's actually not clear to me is:  is $\neg P$ considered a sentence consisting of a single variable?

Comment: @Aemilius Maybe you meant: there is one variable (say $P$), and all sentences are constructed of that variable, but nothing else. So, you have $P$, $\neg P$, $P \land P$, $P \rightarrow \neg (P \lor \neg P)$, etc.  Is that what you meant?  ... But then: you'd have only $2$ ways to assign a truth-value, not $4$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant

Comment: @Aemilius Ah, ok, I'll update my answer!